# Ruby 1.9.2 - Read and parse a remote CSV

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, rvm

I am looking for a way to read and parse locally a remote CSV (hosted on a particular website).

I found on the Internet a couple of interesting examples that make use of FasterCSV, that in ruby 1.9.2 has been merged into CSV. I found that you can read a remote CSV using the gems 'csv' and 'open-uri' this way:

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

def read(url)
  open(url) do |f|
    f.each_line do |l|
      CSV.parse(l) do |row|
        puts row
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I call this function, I get an exception:

```
ERROR IOError: closed stream
```

Anyone can explain me why? Is there anything wrong? Should I choose another approach for reading remote CSV's?

#### Update

The best solution I've found till now is this:

```
def read(url)
  data = []
  begin
    open(url) do |f|
      data = CSV.parse f
    end
  rescue IOError => e
    # Silently catch the exception ...
  end

  return data
end
```

but it somewhat seems not so clean. I really do not like silently catching an exception where it shouldn't be ...

#### Update 2

I can reproduce the error using both

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

and

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
```

This is the code from my `test.rb` file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

def read(url)
  data = []
  begin
    open(url) do |f|
      data = CSV.parse f
    end
  end

  puts data
end

read("http://www.euribor-ebf.eu/assets/modules/rateisblue/processed_files/myav_EURIBOR_2011.csv")
```

And this is the output of the `ruby test.rb` command

```
/Users/marzu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:152:in `close': closed stream (IOError)
from /Users/marzu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:152:in `open_uri'
from /Users/marzu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
from /Users/marzu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
from test.rb:8:in `read'
from test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I am using `rvm 1.6.9` on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Uhm ... could it be a problem with the CSV? Could you please give me the URL you tried? Thank you

Comment: If no one can reproduce your problem it does not help to provide a solution for which we will also have no basis for comment.

Comment: I can reproduce it, obviously. Please, try with this URL: http://www.euribor-ebf.eu/assets/modules/rateisblue/processed_files/myav_EURIBOR_2011.csv

Comment: Ok, thank you, but it still works, both on **ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.0]** and on **ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]**

Comment: Posting more information about the error might help.

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.2-p0 and not 1.9.2-p180. I think that the error may be linked to this old version of ruby. I'm upgrading right now. Will let you know

Comment: Upgraded but the error is still there. I updated the question with more detailed data on the error, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.6.7, using ruby r1.9.2, I get the same error as displayed above. But using the following code to read CSV files works for the example URL provided:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

def read(url)
 CSV.new(open(url), :headers => :first_row).each do |line|
   puts line
   puts line[0]
   puts line['FEB11']
 end
end

read("http://www.euribor-ebf.eu/assets/modules/rateisblue/processed_files/myav_EURIBOR_2011.csv")
```

Comment: Great. This now works fine! I didn't try the CSV.new() method.

Comment: Awesome, That really saved my time. `CSV.new(open(url))`

Comment: If you linter complains about security issues with open, you can reemplace it with `URI.parse(url).open`.