# NameError: undefined local variable or method `table' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to set up a csv url to save the data from the csv into my database after truncating the database first.

However when i run the rake for it, it seems to fall over at this.

LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Gigantictable, expected /Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/app/models/gigantictable.rb to define it

Now my model is totally empty, I am guessing, I am supposed to have something inside there.

```
require 'open-uri'
namespace :populate do
   task reload: :environment do
       Gigantictable.delete_all
       url = "Private url here"
       CSV.open(url).each do |row|
         Gigantictable.create(name: row[0], address: row[1])
       end
   end
end
```

I've named the table `gigantictable` in my DB and all the titles in the first row are put as the headers in the database (excluding the id of the first column in the database)

Any help would be lovely!

So i've found a mistake, I had it as class Gigantictables nto table.

This error is now the main error

```
bundle exec rake populate:reload
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "gigantictables" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "gigantictables"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "gigantictables"
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:173:in `exec_delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:119:in `delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:478:in `delete_all'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `delete_all'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/lib/tasks/populate.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "gigantictables" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "gigantictables"
                    ^
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:173:in `exec_delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:119:in `delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:478:in `delete_all'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `delete_all'
/Users/samroberts/Desktop/project/lib/tasks/populate.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => populate:reload
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Sam

Comment: Is there in your model something like `class Gigantictable < ActiveRecord::Base` ??

Comment: Just that, (well with end on the end)

Comment: opps realized a typo, Check the edit i've found

Comment: Did you forgot to run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: now have `NameError: uninitialized constant CSV` line 6

Comment: Placed `require 'csv'` in the model and i got `no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  may also need to:
`require 'csv'` 
on the top of the file.
Consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005139/ruby-1-9-2-read-and-parse-a-remote-csv).

Comment: pratically what i was missing!